# Can a Ball Really Bounce an Infinite Amount of Times Before Stopping?

Tags: limits

So lets say a ball is dropped from a starting position of $1$ meter. And every bounce is half as high as the previous one. Obviously, this is an exponential function with an asymptote on the x-axis. So does a ball really bounce an infinite amount of times? I would think so, because the time between every bounce is also getting exponentially smaller.

Comment: Theoretically it does (in some mathematically perfect world). But in the real world, no. See Planck-length and Planck-time.

Comment: All models are wrong. And that’s a good thing.

Comment: @stuartstevenson Thanks I will definitely look into that.

Comment: @IttayWeiss What do you mean?